# Trying to sort a dict by dict.values()

Tags: python, dictionary

The task is to read a file, create a dict and print out the word and its counter value. Below is code that works fine, but I can't seem to get my mind to understand why in the print_words() function, I can't change the sort to:

```
words = sorted(word_count.values())
```

and then print the word and its counter, sorted by the counter (number of times that word is in word_count[]).

```
def word_count_dict(filename):
  word_count = {}
  input_file = open(filename, 'r')
  for line in input_file:
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
      word = word.lower()
      if not word in word_count:
        word_count[word] = 1
      else:
        word_count[word] = word_count[word] + 1
input_file.close()
return word_count


def print_words(filename):
  word_count = word_count_dict(filename)
  words = sorted(word_count.keys())
  for word in words:
    print word, word_count[word]
```

Comment: It is convenient to use `defaultdict` on such tasks, instead of ordinary `dict`, then you don't have to check if the key is already there, don't have to initialize the key, can just do `word_count[word] += 1` right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you sorted output by value (including the keys), the simplest approach is sorting the `items` (key-value pairs), using a `key` argument to `sorted` that sorts on the value, then iterating the result. So for your example, you'd replace:

```
words = sorted(word_count.keys())
for word in words:
    print word, word_count[word]
```

with (adding `from operator import itemgetter` to the top of the module):

```
# key=itemgetter(1) means the sort key is the second value in each key-value
# tuple, meaning the value
sorted_word_counts = sorted(word_count.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
for word, count in sorted_word_counts:
    print word, count
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing to note is that dictionaries are not considered to be ordered, although this may change in the future. Therefore, it is good practice to convert your `dict` to a list of tuples ordered in some way.

The below function will help you convert a dictionary to a list of tuples ordered by values.

```
d = {'a': 5, 'b': 1, 'c': 7, 'd': 3}

def order_by_values(dct):
    rev = sorted((v, k) for k, v in dct.items())
    return [t[::-1] for t in rev]

order_by_values(d)  # [('b', 1), ('d', 3), ('a', 5), ('c', 7)]
```

Comment: This will lose data, because the values (counts) cannot be assumed to be unique (try it with `d = {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}`), but using them as keys in a new `dict` will only preserve one key for each distinct count, no matter how many keys have that count. It's trivial to fix though, just don't create a `dict` unnecessarily from the reversed pairs; it's actually simpler as a trivial one-liner: `return sorted((v, k) for k, v in dct.items())`

Comment: @ShadowRange, thank you - good point, updated. i still want to reverse it to have (letter, num) tuples, so will keep at 2 lines :)